# Hide Show Animation Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide and show navbar smoothly on mouse move , it is working but time after show and hide is not working, means it is not smooth. This is the code given below. Under .navHideShow class I have my navbar.

```
<div class="navHideShow" style="display: none">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <span class="primarycolor">BIG </span><span 
            class="fontChange">MUSCLE</span>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
        target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-edit" href="#top">HOME <span 
                    class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-edit" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-edit" href="#course">COURSES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-edit" href="#trainers">TRAINERS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-edit" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var myVar;

$("html").mousemove(function (event) {
    $(".navHideShow").show(1000);

    myStopFunction();
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".navHideShow").hide(1000);
    }, 2000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    if (typeof myVar != 'undefined') {
        clearTimeout(myVar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the HTML code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace `show` with `fadeIn`, and `hide` with `fadeOut`?

Would this give you the desired effect?

**EDIT:**
Use this library provided via jQuery CDN.

`<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: What in particular does not work? Do your functions still run? What is in the console?

Comment: 132Logic.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeIn is not a function
    at HTMLHtmlElement.<anonymous> (Logic.js:51)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)

Comment: you need to use plain jquery library instead of jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js.

Comment: @kawaldeepSingh - As Mr. Roshan said, you can use the `fadeIn` & `fadeOut` functions if you use the complete jQuery library.

Comment: Can You Send me the link for plain jquery library

Comment: @KawaldeepSingh - Please see my edit, I've added the link there

Comment: Instead of fade in or fade out. Is there any other animations that we can use like swipeup or swipedown. Because fadein and fadeout is not looking good on top of the images.

Comment: @KawaldeepSingh - Sure, you can check out the full list of jQuery animations in the jQuery docs, but here are some from W3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: how to use slideUp and SlideDown slowly instead of fadeIn and fadeOut?

Comment: @KawaldeepSingh - The first param taken is for the duration, in milliseconds. See here: http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Answer (score 0):

you need to use plain JQuery (`jquery.min.js`) Library instead of `jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js.`

```js
var myVar;

$("html").mousemove(function (event) {
    $(".navHideShow").show(1000);

    myStopFunction();
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".navHideShow").hide(1000);
    }, 2000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    if (typeof myVar != 'undefined') {
        clearTimeout(myVar);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navHideShow" style="display: none">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <span class="primarycolor">BIG </span><span 
            class="fontChange">MUSCLE</span>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
        target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-edit" href="#top">HOME <span 
                    class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-edit" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-edit" href="#course">COURSES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-edit" href="#trainers">TRAINERS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-edit" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use below code and update the fadeIn and FadeOut time according to need.**

```
$("html").mousemove(function (event) {
    $(".navHideShow").fadeIn(1000);

    myStopFunction();
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    /*myVar = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".navHideShow").fadeOut('slow',1000);
    }, 2000);*/
    $(".navHideShow").fadeOut(4000,"swing", function () {
        $(".navHideShow").fadeIn(5000,"swing");
    });

}

function myStopFunction() {
    if (typeof myVar != 'undefined') {
        clearTimeout(myVar);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use on scroll of the mouse inplace of mousemove?